# .htaccess force http specific sub directories

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have set in my .htaccess file to redirect every url to https.

What i want to add is to exclude it for a specific sub directory

eg: www.mysite.com/myfiles <-- dont force https
eg: www.mysite.com/everythingelse <-- force https

my .htaccess so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```